# Assigning enums to other enum values

Tags: d

I'm using D and SDL to create a simple game. I'm trying to create a wrapper around SDL so that i'm not working with it directly. Right now I'm trying to create my own Input class as far removed from SDL's input as possible. However, i'm having some trouble assigning correct enum values for keyboard keys.

So far I've tried, assigning SDL's enums for keyboard keys, because that seemed the easiest but it doens't seem to be working, nothing prints to console.

--SDLInput--

```
import derelict.sdl.sdl;
import SDLApp;

class SDLInput
{
private:
    SDLApp sdlapp;
    SDL_Event event;
public:
    this()
    {
        event = sdlapp.event;
    }

    bool KeyPressed(SDLKey key)
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == key)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool KeyReleased(SDLKey key)
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == key)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

--DPInput--

```
import SDLInput;
import derelict.sdl.sdl; //Eventually I'd get rid of this, only here for testing

class DPInput
{
private:
    SDLInput sdlinput;

public:
    enum DPKey
    {
        DPK_SPACE = SDLK_SPACE
    }

    this()
    {
        sdlinput = new SDLInput;
    }

    bool KeyPressed(DPKey key)
    {
        return sdlinput.KeyPressed(key);
    }
}
```

--DPApp--

```
import SDLApp;
import DPInput;
import DPTime;
import std.stdio;

class DPApp
{
    //...
    void Run()
    {
        Init();
        Loop();
        Cleanup();
    }


    void Loop()
    {
        dptime.InitNextTime();

        while(gameRunning)
        {
            if(sdlapp.PollQuit())
                gameRunning = false;

            UpdateGame();
            Render();

            dptime.DPDelay(dptime.TimeLeft());
            dptime.UpdateNextTime();
        }
    }

    void UpdateGame()
    {
        if(dpinput.KeyPressed(dpinput.DPKey.DPK_SPACE))
            writeln("DPAPP: SPACE PRESSED");
    }

}
```

//..main here calling run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know SDL, at all, but I see some possible problems with this code:

**1)** Where does `event` in `SDLInput` get updated? It looks like you assume an `SDL_Event` will always contain the latest "state" automatically? I have a feeling it won't.

Note that `SDL_Event` is probably a struct (?) and doing `this.event = app.event;` will copy the event at that exact point, and you now have two distinct event objects in two different places and updating one won't update the other. (If `SDL_Event` is a class, however, then `this.event` will refer to the same object as `app.event`.)

**2)** Although it's very difficult to tell, since the code is incomplete, I do think this code is confused about how events work. This design, from what I can see, means you can only ever handle one event every frame, and any additional events will simply get dropped.

Imagine a user pressing down two buttons at the same time. This would generate two key-down events, possibly in one frame, yet you have one event object that I presume you'll overwrite with any incoming events, and then you read this object. You risk dropping events in the process. Also, there's no possible way of knowing whether a particular key is pressed by looking only at the last event. If two keys got pressed and you only look at the last event, you can't possibly know if the first key is down or not, that information is then lost for ever.

The conventional way is to let an event dispatcher call some functions and pass an event object with some extra information about the event and then keep your own input states. This would happend outside of your `update()`-function and it could happend more than once before `update()`. For instance you could have something like:

```
// Pseudo code
bool keys[256];

void keyDown(Event e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

void keyUp(Event e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

void update(){
    if(keys[KEY_W])
        movePlayerForward();
    if(keys[KEY_SPACE])
        jumpPlayer();
}

void loop(){
    while(true){
        fireAllQueuedEvents(); // Could call keyUp/Down several times
        update();
        render();
    }
}
```

`fireAllQueuedEvents()` can fire more than one event, and it would work correctly. Here both W and Spacebar can be pressed at the same time, and the player would jump and move. Now, I don't know how to do this in SDL or how to deal with input the "SDL-way", so yeah, unless you know, to the [docs-mobile](http://www.libsdl.org/)! I guess..

Generally though, in event handling there needs to be an event queue somewhere. I suspect SDL has one or is relying on the underlying OS:es event queue. At some point this queue needs to dispatch waiting events and I suspect SDL has functions for intercepting these events at that time. That's where you need to hook in your system, and you need to respond to events as-they-happen and then update your own data structures for key up/down states etc. that you later use in your `update()`. It doesn't really makes sense to store event objects around and look at them later to check if a key is pressed, as you'd have to, in the worst case, store at least a dozen event objects, in order, and go through them all just to figure out if one key is up or down. Event objects don't describe the "grand state" of things, they just describe a *single change*. And it looks like you're just checking the latest change. This won't work with multiple keys/events.

As for the enum-assignment: That looks correct.

(Good luck with the game :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were right that this.event did not contain the current, up-to-date event. This is my first foray into constructing a game by myself (I've done others with aid of a book or tutorial) so there I am expecting the code to be bad with many errors. I edited how I handle events, and now I get output to the console. I am going to go back and implement your event handling structure, it looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get me wrong, I am not against the DIY approach, but if You want to get your project going, try not to re-invent the wheel at the early stage - use tools that are already there for you, done (and tested) by hundreds of developers.

This said, i wholeheartedly recommend You use the excellent Derelict2 - http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict . It already contains all you wrote above, and more (almost all core SDL libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to D, and a new programmer in general (about 6 months of experience), so there's a lot I have yet to learn. As far as my understanding of derelict2, is that it just loads the sdl library. How can I use derelict2 to properly get my project going?

Comment: Start with Derelict examples, and the more you play with it, the more easy it will be for you to make your game the way you want it.